# Excel VBA Macro Conditional Formatting with Intersect

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote an Excel VBA macro to do conditional formatting using an intersect of two columns but I can't get it to work for some reason.  If anyone has any idea on what I can do to fix it, I would sincerely appreciate it.

I want to highlight both the source and the target columns in which there is a match or duplicate as follows:

E Column (Target)
0.0000%
0.0000%
11.1803%
12.7775%
13.7190%
13.9841%
13.9841%
14.5698%
14.9071%
15.5746%
15.6492%
16.1355%
16.1355%
16.3123%
16.3123%
19.0693%
19.4511%
21.9089%
21.9089%
21.9089%

V Column (Source)
13.7190%
14.9240%
15.4919%
20.4521%
21.5725%
23.3319%
23.7718%
24.1871%
25.7257%
27.2166%
28.2290%
29.7543%
29.7543%
30.4968%
31.0080%
31.9022%
32.8570%
33.3333%
33.3333%
34.7434%
34.9603%
34.9927%
36.4516%
36.8697%
37.5637%
38.2046%
38.6151%
38.7298%
38.7298%
39.3830%
40.2694%
41.8330%
42.2049%

```
Sub Highlight_rsd_5batch()
Dim WatchRange As Range, Target As Range, cell As Range
Set Target = Range("E19:E237") 'change column ref as required
Set WatchRange = Range("V19:V237")

For Each cell In Target.Cells
If Intersect(Target, WatchRange) Is Nothing Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Else: cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Intersect` function checks to see if the two ranges have any cells in common, not if they have values in common.  You could use the `CountIf` function instead:

```
Sub Highlight_rsd_5batch()
    Dim WatchRange As Range, Target As Range, cell As Range
    Set Target = Range("E19:E237") 'change column ref as required
    Set WatchRange = Range("V19:V237")

    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WatchRange,cell.Value) > 0 Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            For Each watchCell in WatchRange.Cells
                If watchCell.value = cell.Value Then: watchCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Next watchCell
        Else: cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

This task does not really require the use of VBA and could be accomplished using the same formulas in the Conditional Formatting tools under Format>Conditional Formatting.  See the linked [tutorial](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html) for more help.

Comment: Mark, thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  I really appreciate it.  This is my first shot at writing an Excel macro and learning more about programming. Your code had a syntax error; specifically cell.Value: so I changed the ":" to "Then" but now I have a compile error in "Next watchCell" as it says "Next Without For".  I don't understand as there is a For statement above.

Comment: I have made an edit to the code.  It should be a `Then:` if you want to have the statement on the same line.  Otherwise it will throw an error because you do not have a closing `EndIf` before the `Next`.

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you very much.